# Options for authentication between C++ service and Azure AD web api in ASP .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-web-api, visual-c++, azure-active-directory, adal, azure-ad-msal

I have a web api written in ASP .NET Core 3.1, hosted in Azure, and I would like a windows service, on premise, written in C++, to access this api. But I would ideally like the service to authenticate to Azure AD so i know the identity of the request.

As far as I can tell, this either cannot be done (there is no C++ library for ADAL/MSAL) or, if using the REST API, there is no ability to go through the login/consent user interaction.

The other option is certificate authentication but having never used that I am not sure what identity comes in on requests or even if certificate authentication is an option.

Some more information. This is a single tenant application used internally at my work, we have Azure AD and Office 365, I dont know what else we have in regards to federation or whatever.

What are my options given this list of requirements:

1. C++ non interactive client (or if can trigger some dialog from code then sure)
2. Want to authenticate to a web API using Azure AD or some other way that I can determine the identity of the user without a seperate database (can i somehow use Windows credentials?)
3. I want this API locked down to only my tenant (which I would get for free with AD auth but not with JWT). I assume certificate authentication would solve this one but not identity?